# How can I get this regex match to fail?

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-negation

I want a regex that matches a two-digit year range and the word `Caterpillar` or `Ford` like this:

```
ABC123 08-10 Caterpillar
```

But not this:

```
ABC123 fits 08-10 Caterpillar
```

or this:

```
ABC123 for 08-10 Caterpillar XYZ789
```

The `ABC123` and `XYZ789` can vary and contain anything.

I'm trying to replace the word `Caterpillar` with `fits Caterpillar` using `gsub`, but I don't want to do it on strings that already contain `fits` or `for`. Captures are important so that I can figure out how to do the `gsub`.

I have written this:

```
/([^fits]\s?\d{2}-\d{2}\s*(Ford|Caterpillar))/
```

But the above regex matches all three of my example strings. So my word negation is not correct. And the year range needs to be optional. I want to put that in square brackets but I don't think I'm doing that right, I think that's to denote a range.

Comment: What is `Ford` is your regex? Do you mean nothing should come after `Caterpillar`?

Comment: Try `s.gsub(/(?<!\bfits\s)(?<!\bfor\s)(\d{2}-\d{2})\s*(Caterpillar)\z/, '\1 fits \2')`

Comment: I edited the question, last component can be either Ford or Caterpillar.

Comment: Try `^(?!.*?\b(?:fits|for)\b)(.*?\b\d\d-\d\d\s+)(Caterpillar|Ford)\r?$` and replace with `\1fits \2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to convert my comment into an answer with a bit of modification. Use the following regex to find the matches:

```
(?<!fits|for)(\b\s+\d\d-\d\d\s+)(Caterpillar|Ford)(?!.*\S)
```

*Note: `\b` is necessary.*

and for the replacement string:

```
\1fits \2
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/jO6FHf/1)

Ruby code:

```
re = /(?<!fits|for)(\b\s+\d\d-\d\d\s+)(Caterpillar|Ford)(?!.*\S)/

str = 'ABC123 08-10 Caterpillar
ABC123 fits 08-10 Caterpillar
ABC123 for 08-10 Caterpillar XYZ789'

subst = '\\1fits \\2'

print str.gsub(re, subst)
```

**Explanation**:

Your current regex comes with a semantic error: `[^fits]` doesn't mean `fits`, but it means **a character** that is neither `f`, `i`, `t`, nor `s`. You need a lookaround (lookahead / lookbehind) to express **the negation of a character string**.

I used lookbehind to say so and a negative lookahead to check if a non-space character is not coming after `Caterpillar` or `Ford`.

Comment: This is super, super helpful. Thanks! But how can I make the years optional? My goodness but these things are stubborn.

Comment: Replace `\d\d-\d\d\s+` with `(?:\d\d-\d\d\s+)?`.

Comment: I can't get that to pick up the last line in the sample, where the line begins with Caterpillar. New link is https://regex101.com/r/jO6FHf/2

Comment: Oh now I get it, that's not 4 strings, it's one multiline string. I have learned a lot, and that is a GREAT site.

Answer (score 0):

The regex below meets your requirements, but you will have do the substitution part

See that I used the Negative Lookahead (?!) to exclude the lines that has the string "fits"

```
^(((?!fits).)*((\d{2}-\d{2}\s)Caterpillar))$
```

you can test this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/uJk13d/1/)